# Para que sirve el operador ? : (operador condicional) en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una pequeña duda con el siguiente código:

```
int n1 = 20;

int n2 = 10;

int n3 = (n1 > n2) ? n1:0;

Console.WriteLine(n3);
Console.ReadKey();
```

No entiendo porque `n3` termina siendo 20 
¿Qué roles cumplen el `?` y el `n1:0` en ese caso?

Comment: Enlace muy recomendado para tu aprendizaje en C#: https://mva.microsoft.com

Comment: se llama operador ternario, y viene muy bien en muchos casos.

Comment: @Veelicus Corrección: Se llama operador condicional (ternario sólo quiere decir que tiene 3 argumentos, así como los operadores binarios tienen 2 y los unarios solo 1)

Comment: Acepta una respuesta mediante un click en el check verde del costado. Así nos ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio basado en % de preguntas resueltas. Saludos

Answer (score 8):

Es un IF corto,

```
int n3 = (n1 > n2) ? n1:0;
```

Esto se traduce como:

```
int n3;
if(n1>n2){
 n3 = n1;
}else{
 n3 = 0;
}
```

Te recomiendo que utilices el "if corto" cuando tengas una estructura sencilla como el ejemplo presente.

Comment: Muy claro. Muchas gracias fredy!!

Comment: de nada hermano, acepta la respuesta mediante un click en el check verde del costado. Así nos ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio basado en % de preguntas resueltas. Éxitos con el desarrollo! Dale con todo el power! :D

Comment: Se le conoce como Operador ternario y existe en varios lenguajes de programación, incluso en Excel. Puedes encontrar mas información en la siguiente página: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx y ejemplos tanto en C# como en VB en la siguiente: https://varionet.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/operador-ternario-en-c-y-vby/

Answer (score 0):

Esto Pasa ya que este tipo de operación hace una comprobación antes de asignar un valor a la variable.

var valor = ( condición ) ? verdadero : falso;

verdadero: asigna el valor si la condición es verdadera.

falso: asigna el valor si la condición es falsa.

por si te ha quedado alguna duda te dejo una [documentación.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)